# Controller Extension Test Class - Method is not visible

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller-extension

Need some help with updating a controller extension test class. I am getting a "method is not visible: test_session_and_session_benefit.testCreateSessions()" error.

This test class is being rewritten from an old version created by another programmer. 
Here is the test class for the controller extension:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class TestExt_EmpSessionBenefit {
    testMethod static void testEmpSessionBenefit() {

        Employee_Session__c         employeeSession             = Test_Session_and_Session_Benefit.testCreateSessions();

        Test.setCurrentPage(Page.SessionBenefit);
        ext_EmpSessionBenefit controller = new ext_EmpSessionBenefit(new ApexPages.StandardController(employeeSession));
        controller.loadESBs();
        pageReference pr = controller.saveChangesNewPage();
        controller.reload();
        controller.saveChanges();
        controller.reload();
        pageReference pradmin = controller.saveAdminNewPage();
        controller.reload();
        controller.saveAdminChanges();
        controller.doNothing();
        controller.reload();
        pagereference prsched = controller.scheduleReview();
        controller.reload();
        pagereference prAdminTask = controller.assignFollowUpTask();
        controller.reload();

    }
}
```

Here is my test class for the trigger on this object. I am trying to use this test class as it does all the work for setting up the accounts, employees, and other needed bits. This is a brand new test class that i have created from scratch.

```
@isTest
global class Test_Session_and_Session_Benefit {
    //Created by Matt - March 2016
    //Designed for the Acorn Release

    //Create Users, Accounts, Public Groups, Hubs, etc....
    //First Employee Session is a Full Benefit Review
    //Session Date: 10 months ago on first of month.
    @testSetup static void setupTestData(){
        //huge chunk of code creating test users,accounts,employees,benefits, etc...
    }

    //Create Basic Acorn Sessions  
    @isTest static void testCreateSessions(){

        User uBCS = [Select Id,Name FROM User WHERE Alias = 'TSTBCS'];

        System.runAs(uBCS){
            RecordType RecType = [Select Id from RecordType WHERE Name = 'Standard EE Session - Acorn'];
            Employees__c emp = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Employees__c LIMIT 1];
            BCS__c theHub = [SELECT Id, Name, User__c FROM BCS__c WHERE User__c = :uBCS.Id];


            test.startTest();

            List<Employee_Session__c> session = new List<Employee_Session__c>();

            //Create Review session - Full Review    
            Session.add(new Employee_Session__c(
                RecordTypeId                        = RecType.Id,
                Employee__c                         = emp.Id,
                Session_Date__c                     = Date.today().addMonths(-2).toStartOfMonth(),
                Specialist__c                       = theHub.Id,
                Intro_with_Compliance_Verbiage__c   = TRUE,
                Core__c                             = TRUE,
                Voluntary_Benefits__c               = TRUE,
                Conclusion__c                       = TRUE
            ));

            //Create Service Session
            session.add(new Employee_Session__c(
                RecordTypeId                        = RecType.Id,
                Employee__c                         = emp.Id,
                Session_Date__c                     = Date.today().addMonths(-2).toStartOfMonth(),
                Specialist__c                       = theHub.Id,
                Session_Status__c                   = 'Service',
                Session_Type__c                     = 'Service',
                Intro_with_Compliance_Verbiage__c   = TRUE           
            ));

            //Create Refused Review
            session.add(new Employee_Session__c(
                RecordTypeId                        = RecType.Id,
                Employee__c                         = emp.Id,
                Session_Date__c                     = Date.today().addMonths(-2).toStartOfMonth(),
                Specialist__c                       = theHub.Id,
                EE_Refused_Review__c                = TRUE           
            ));


            try {
                insert session;
            } catch(DmlException e) {
                System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            }

            //system.debug('Sessions = ' + session);  

            //Enroll in all benefits for session. 
            List<Employee_Session_Benefit__c> sessionBenefit = new List<Employee_Session_Benefit__c>();
            sessionBenefit = [SELECT Id, Name, Employee_Session__c, Election_Status__c, Premium__c FROM Employee_Session_Benefit__c];


            for( Employee_Session_Benefit__c sb:sessionBenefit){
                sb.Election_Status__c    = 'Enrolled - Paper';
                sb.Premium__c            = 10.00;
                //system.debug('sessionBenefit = '+sb.Id+' '+sb.Name+' '+sb.Election_Status__c+' '+sb.Premium__c);
            }

            try {
                update sessionBenefit;
            } catch(DmlException e) {
                System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            }

            test.stopTest();

        }
    }

}
```

In case someone wants to see it here is my visualforce page:

```
 <apex:page standardController="Employee_Session__c" extensions="ext_EmpSessionBenefit">

    <br/>

    <apex:form id="theForm" >
        <apex:pageMessages />

        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:outputPanel id="Success" layout="block" rendered="{!success}">
            <apex:pageMessage summary="Success" severity="info" />
            <script>
            window.top.location='/{!employeeId}';
            </script>
        </apex:outputPanel> 

        <apex:outputPanel id="Fail" layout="block" rendered="{!!success}" >
            <apex:outputText value="{!errorMessages}" escape="false"/>

        </apex:outputPanel>


        <apex:outputPanel id="Detail" layout="block" title="Detail">


            <apex:pageBlock id="pb_BenUnderReview" title="Benefits Under Admin Review" rendered="{!adminRender}" >

                <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbt_myTable_2" value="{!esb_List_review}" var="rev" >

                    <apex:column headerValue="Account Benefit" > 
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!rev.Account_Benefit__r.id}" target="_blank">{!rev.Account_Benefit__r.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Election Status" >
                        <apex:inputField value="{!rev.Election_Status__c}" rendered="{!paperRender}" />
                        <apex:outputText value="{!rev.Election_Status__c}" rendered="{!!paperRender}" />
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Paper Status" >
                        <apex:inputField value="{!rev.Paper_Status__c}" rendered="{!paperRender}" />
                        <apex:outputText value="{!rev.Paper_Status__c}" rendered="{!!paperRender}" />  
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Incomplete Reason" >
                        <apex:inputField value="{!rev.Incomplete_Reason__c}" rendered="{!incompleteRender}" />
                        <apex:outputText value="{!rev.Incomplete_Reason__c}" rendered="{!!incompleteRender}" />  
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Per Payroll Premium" >
                        <apex:inputField value="{!rev.Premium__c}" rendered="{!paperRender}" />
                        <apex:outputText value="{!rev.Premium__c}" rendered="{!!paperRender}" />
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Volume" rendered="{!showVolume}"> 
                        <apex:inputField value="{!rev.Volume__c}" rendered="{!paperRender && rev.Account_Benefit__r.Show_Volume__c}"/>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!rev.Volume__c}" rendered="{!!paperRender && rev.Account_Benefit__r.Show_Volume__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Elimination Period" rendered="{!showEliminationPeriod}"  >
                        <apex:inputField value="{!rev.Elimination_Period__c}" rendered="{!paperRender && rev.Account_Benefit__r.Show_Elimination_Period__c}"/>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!rev.Elimination_Period__c}" rendered="{!!paperRender && rev.Account_Benefit__r.Show_Elimination_Period__c}"/> 
                    </apex:column>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>

                <apex:pageBlockButtons id="pbb_save_admin" location="bottom" rendered="{!adminButtons}" >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!saveAdminNewPage}" value="Save Admin Changes" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>  

            </apex:pageBlock>

            <!-- All versus Active Filter -->

            <apex:pageBlock id="pb_Ben"  title="Benefits" rendered="{!!serviceSession}">

                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!hasGrandfatheredBenefits}" >
                    <apex:pageBlockSection >
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputText value="Benefits Filter: " />
                            <apex:selectList value="{!benefitType}" size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!benefitTypes}" />
                                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!loadESBs}" rerender="Detail" status="status"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:outputPanel>  

                <!-- Active Benefits Section-->

                <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbt_myTable" value="{!esb_List}" var="ben" rendered="{!!serviceSession}">

                    <apex:column style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}" >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Account Benefit</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.id}" target="_blank">{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>


                    <apex:column headerValue="Election Status" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Election_Status__c}" rendered="{!!selfServiceSession}"/>
                        <apex:outputField value="{!ben.Election_Status__c}" rendered="{!selfServiceSession}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Paper Status" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Paper_Status__c}" rendered="{!paperRender && !selfServiceSession}" />
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Paper_Status__c}" rendered="{!!paperRender && !!selfServiceSession}" />  
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Incomplete Reason" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Incomplete_Reason__c}" rendered="{!incompleteRender && !selfServiceSession}" />
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Incomplete_Reason__c}" rendered="{!!incompleteRender && !!selfServiceSession}" />  
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Per Payroll Premium" id="Premium" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Premium__c}" rendered="{!!selfServiceSession}"/> 
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Premium__c}" rendered="{!selfServiceSession}"/> 
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Volume" rendered="{!showVolume}" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}"> 
                        <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Volume__c}" rendered="{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.Show_Volume__c}" />
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Elimination Period" rendered="{!showEliminationPeriod}" style="{!if(ben.Account_Benefit__r.Grandfathered__c = TRUE,'background:#BDB76B;', '')}">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!ben.Elimination_Period__c}" rendered="{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.Show_Elimination_Period__c}"/> 
                    </apex:column>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>

                <apex:pageBlockButtons id="pbb_save" location="bottom" rendered="{!!selfServiceSession}">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!saveChangesNewPage}" value="Save Voluntary Info" rendered="{!!serviceSession}"/>
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!ScheduleReview}" value="Save,Schedule Review" target="_blank" rendered="{!!serviceSession}" styleclass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;" />
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!assignFollowUpTask}" value="Save,Assign Follow-Up Task" target="_blank" rendered="{!!serviceSession}" styleclass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;" />
                </apex:pageBlockButtons> 

            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <br/>
        <!--Inactive Benefits-->

        <apex:outputPanel id="Inactive" layout="block" title="Inactive">

            <apex:pageBlock id="pb_Inactive_Ben"  title="Inactive Benefits (Reference Only)" rendered="{!inactiveRender}">

                <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbt_InactiveBen" value="{!esb_List_inactive}" var="ben" rendered="{!inactiveRender}">

                    <apex:column headerValue="Account Benefit">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.id}" target="_blank">{!ben.Account_Benefit__r.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Election Status" >
                        <apex:outputField value="{!ben.Election_Status__c}" rendered="True"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Paper Status" >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Paper_Status__c}" rendered="TRUE" />  
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Incomplete Reason" >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Incomplete_Reason__c}" rendered="TRUE" />  
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Per Payroll Premium" >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Premium__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Volume" rendered="TRUE"> 
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Volume__c}" rendered="TRUE" />
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Elimination Period" rendered="TRUE"  >
                        <apex:outputText value="{!ben.Elimination_Period__c}" rendered="TRUE" />
                    </apex:column>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>

            </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputpanel >
            <apex:actionstatus id="status">
                <apex:facet name="start">
                    <div class="waitingSearchDiv" id="el_loading" style="background-color: #fbfbfb;
                                                                         height: 100%;opacity:0.65;width:100%;"> 
                        <div class="waitingHolder" style="top: 50px; width: 91px;">
                            <img class="waitingImage" src="/img/loading.gif" title="Please Wait..." />
                            <span class="waitingDescription">Please Wait...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionstatus>
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly defining `testCreateSessions` as public instead.

this would be the header:

`@isTest public static void testCreateSessions(){`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign from a `void` method. In addition to the visibility being wrong, you need a method that actually returns `Employee_Session__c`.

```
public Employee_Session__c setup()
{
    // do stuff
    // return record
}
```